# scrollView with Memory Management in iOS which is very strange caused EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: memory-management, ios5, uiscrollview, exc-bad-access

Today I got a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" ,so I debug the code to solve the problem. Now I find out where
the problem is, but I don't know why. Can you help me ?

in the 
    -(void) dealloc
    {
    ....
     [self.scrollView release]; 
    // if I add comment to this line above ,my app will work, else it will die.
    ......

## }

these are the places where I used the [scrollView]

```
@interface ChatFriendInfoController :UIViewController
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
}
```

### @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

```
@implementation ChatFriendInfoController
@synthesize scrollView;

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 416);
self.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 960);
```

## [self.scrollView addSubview:infoTable];

That's All . Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the @property line for scrollView is defined with "retain", then the accessor functions that XCode builds for you will already have retain and release calls built-in.

So, any time you use self.scrollview = , you are actually calling [self setScrollView:]  which will release any previous object and retain the new one. So you can release the object and set the variable to nil with just  self.scrollview = nil;

With the code above,  I can't tell if you allocating and initializing a new UIScrollView object.  If you haven't, then there is nothing to release and trying to do so will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to release the scrollView without using self.

```
[scrollView release];
```

Else

```
self.scrollView = nil;
```